# Why is codeigniter giving me a 500 internal server error?

Tags: codeigniter

I have trying doing some research on this topic and couldn't find an answer to my question, so I thought you guys might be able to help.

I am loading a page in codeigniter and its giving me an internal 500 error on firebug console log, but the weird thing is the page is showing perfectly fine.

Any ideas on why that may be happening??

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind guys. I just found out that it seems to be an error with the javascript code that's causing the error message.

Comment: are you sure its javascript error?. I think this happen when any syntax error found in `.htaccess`  file.

Comment: @AniketSingh . I had an undefined php variable in my javascript code which was casuing the issue